# I am having difficulty identifying a specific port on a motherboard

Tags: motherboard, connection

I have an asus motherboard. Model no: a55bm-a/m32bf/dp_mb it has some slot that I took a wireless card out of, and I want to use that slot, but I have no idea what it is. I searched asus support for it, but I don't see this motherboard in their support page. Here is a link for the image

https://goo.gl/images/G7U5Tw

The port I am looking at is the white one beside the pci slot that has 45 AA on it. Can anyone tell me what type of slot that is? Thanks in advance.

Here is an image of the wireless card and a penny by side for scale:

[image]

Comment: To me it looks like a strangely placed PCI-e x4 connector. It also has a very weird orientation by looking at the picture. On the newer A55 boards, that spot is filled with a PCI-e x1.

Comment: Isn't sata only meant for mass storage devices? That port used to have a wireless network card in it, so if my assumption is correct, it cannot be a sata?

Comment: I updated my question. I was on a question about SATA just a minute ago. I made the correction above.

Comment: Oh ok cool. It certainly does seem like a pcie connection. I'll try attaching a pcie device I suppose and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: Could you include a picture of the wireless adapter you took out of it? It might make it easier to conclude an answer. Especially if we can search the part for a model number or something.

Comment: Yes I can. I will go ahead and do that.

Comment: Yep it is indeed a mini PCI-e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its mini PCIe. Not all that uncommon for wireless - since you have parts/slot commonality with laptops.

Not all that much uses for one - In theory you could slot a mini PCIe SSD or another wifi card.

I also know of ethernet adaptors and sata adaptors that are meant for modding NUC class machines too.